# How do I add HKCU Regkeys value for each current user in powershell script?

Tags: powershell, variables, registry

I want a powershell script to run each time a user login to Windows by placed in: *Shell:common startup*.
This script must add about 50 Regkey's in HKCU, which is setting/path for Presetfolders for a application.

I want to use Powershell and have tried this command adding the RegKey (This command needs to be repeated for each 50 regkeys!):
`New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\AppName' -Name 'PresetFolder' -PropertyType String -Value '$env:userprofile\Documents\AppName\Presets1' -Force`
`New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\AppName' -Name 'PresetFolder' -PropertyType String -Value '$env:userprofile\Documents\AppName\Presets2' -Force`  .......

When using `"$env:userprofile"` instead of `c:\Users\MyUserProfile\Documents\....` the -value in the RegKey will be: `"$env:userprofile\Documents\NewFolder\Presets"` and not as wanted: `"c:\Users\MyUserProfile\Documents\NewFolder\Presets"`.
I need a Variable for each userprofile!

Alternatively I can after Program installation by using admin-account, I can exported all RegKey's as a .reg-file. Before using the powershell-script to merge the RegKeys everytime a user is logging in Windows, I now need to search and replace the value of the path (-Value) from AdminUserProfil-path into a variable for each user running the script.

**Part of the Reg-file:**

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\AppName\Version]
"HelpDocPath"="C:\Users\\AdminUserprofiles\\Documents\\AppName\\Version\\HTML Help\\en"
"ExciterCacheInstallPath"="C:\\Program Files\\AppName\\Version\\Exciter Cache"
"DSPResourceFilesInstallPath"="C:\\Program Files\\AppName\\Version/Resources"
"InstallPath"="C:\\Program Files\\AppName\\InstallFolder"
"PresetFolder"="C:\\Users\\AdminUserprofiles\\Documents\\AppName\\Version\\Presets\\Global Presets"\
```

Hope anyone can help?
What do I need to type for the right path, so each user will have there own path? Do I need a variable fo rusers or..?
Thank you.

Comment: Actually `"$env:userprofile"` will work. In your current code you are using single quotes, where PowerShell doesn't do variable substitution. See [About Quoting Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: Could you please explain why you would need to add this information to the users registry location every time they log in? What possible reason would there be that those registry keys, values and string data, to be modified or removed during every session? Additionally, as this is only part of your reg file, are you aware that your first value data uses ```C:\```, whereas the others use ```C:\\```,one uses ```Version/Resources```, as opposed to ```Version\\Resources```, and why is there a trailing backslash at the end of your last line?

Comment: You could also set the registry properties as type `ExpandString` and add like `New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\AppName' -Name 'PresetFolder' -PropertyType ExpandString -Value '%USERPROFILE%\Documents\AppName\Presets1' -Force` I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Define $env:USERPROFILE as a variable so you can call it, otherwise PS will just output what you have typed, which is what is happening in this case.

```
$path = "$env:USERPROFILE"
New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Software\AppName' -Name 'PresetFolder' -PropertyType String -Value '$path\Documents\AppName\Presets1' -Force
```